# t-statistics in gradient boosted machine/forest such LightGBM

Tags: regression, boosting, lightgbm

Is there a t-statistics in the gradient boosted forest regression model such as that in [LightGBM](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)? If so, how is it defined, extracted and used?

Comment: What would that mean? That t-stats in linear regression apply to particular parameters that do not have analogues in other regression models. It sounds like you might have some problem that you aim to solve with t-stats, so you're asking about t-stats in LightGBM instead of asking your original question. Is this the case?

Comment: @Dave: Perhaps I should ask about test/diagnostic measures analogous to t-statistics in LightGBM or other gradient boosted models. Are there such measures?